# How to make constructor templates for specific superclasses?

Tags: java, eclipse, constructor, automation

I have a class, `GamePacket`, from which all packet classes *extend* from.

I wish to create some sort of template function in the Eclipse IDE. Currently, when creating new packet classes, I have to copy this snippet, then edit the individual class names etc. -

```
package lessur.engine.net.packets;

import java.io.IOException;

import lessur.engine.net.GamePacket;
import lessur.engine.net.LessurConnectedNode;

public class PacketTemplate extends GamePacket {

    public PacketTemplate(LessurConnectedNode c) {
        super(-1, c);   
    }

    public PacketTemplate(){
        super(-1, null);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getData() throws IOException {
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }

}
```

Is there any way to automate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [define custom templates](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-custom-templ) in Eclipse.

It's a lot to explain, so I suggest you follow that link.